# Make a Select Box that Calls a Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, tags, link-to

I have a rails app with working reports that have tags. In the Report/Index.html.erb I want the user to be able to sort the reports by selecting a tag. They may only select one tag at a time so I feel that a select box would work best. I currently have this:

```
<%= select("preferences", :tag_with, 
 ["Politics", "Technology", "Entertainment", "Sports", "Science", "Crime", 
 "Business", "Social", "Nature", "Other"], :prompt => "Filter Feed by:" )%>
```

I have a working preferences controller with a method call `tag_with` that updates the current tag. This code, however, only generates the select box. I want it to be that when the user selects one of the tags, it calls the tag_with method from the preferences controller.

I generated a series of `link_to` lines that complete the task, however I would really like a select box.

```
<%= link_to "Politics", :action => "tag_with", :tag => "Politics", :controller =>"preferences" %>
<%= link_to "Entertainment", :action => "tag_with", :tag => "Entertainment", :controller =>"preferences" %>
<%= link_to "Science", :action => "tag_with", :tag => "Science", :controller =>"preferences" %>
<%= link_to "Technology", :action => "tag_with", :tag => "Technology", :controller =>"preferences" %>
```

And so on for each tag. This works fine but is bulky and undesirable. Is there a way to do the same thing through a select box?

Comment: Did you try just binding the onchange event of the select box?

Comment: How could I go about doing that? I wasn't sure what to bind the onChange event to. I have tried onChange => link_to ... but that doesn't work.

Comment: First off this should be done unobtrusively (give the select an id and handle the event in javascript).  See http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript and google results for `unobtrusive javascript rails` for more info.  What version of Rails?  Are you using Coffee Script or just javascript?  Let me know and I'll submit a full answer if you still need help.

Comment: I'm currently using JQuery javascript however I am quite weak with the language. I am using Rails version 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `reports.js.coffee` file, or whatever other js file you want.

```
jQuery ->
  $('select#preferences').change ->
    $.get 'preferences/tag_with',{ term: $('option:selected', this). val() }
```

Or, if you want to use regular javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('select#preferences').change( function() {
    $.get('preferences/tag_with',{term: $('option:selected',this).val()});
  });
});
```

A link is a GET request. The jQuery `.change()` method fires whenever someone makes a change. The `$.get` method sends a GET request to a URL and can pass data (the second argument). This data becomes your params hash, so in the example above you would get:

```
params[:term] #=> the value attribute of whatever option was selected by the user
```

See the jQuery docs on [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more help.

---

**Update**

For this to refresh the page, the easiest thing would be to extract the table that you want changed into a partial, let's assume it's called `_report.html.erb`. The partial should look something like this:

```
<div id="report">
  <%= render @report %>
</div>
```

*Note: `render @report` is just short for `render :partial => 'report'`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html*

In your preferences controller, tag_with option you should be sure to set the `@report` object (or whatever else is delivering the data to your partial).

Then you should make a file called `views/preferences/tag_with.js.erb` and put something like this in it:

```
$('div#report').html('<%= escape_javascript( render @report ) %>');
```

This will update the report container with the new content.

Comment: This works wonderfully! However it only swaps the filter AFTER reloading the page. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: I seems that when I use the link_to I get `Processing by ReportsController#index as HTML` but when I use the select I get `Processing by ReportsController#index as *\*`.
Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: Try using `'preferences/tag_with.js'` as your URL and see what happens.

Comment: It still needs to be refreshed. Is there a way to auto refresh it through JQuery? Or even in the preferences#tag_with method?

Comment: Oh, yes, the page needs to be refreshed with jQuery. Update pending.